# wx.lib.activex fails to import using Enthought Canopy and EPD

Tags: enthought, canopy, epd-python

`import wx.lib.activex` fails with the supplied version of wx in Enthought Canopy or EPD on Windows. How can I get the activex container to work with the Enthought Python Distributions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's necessary to install comtypes, which is a dependency not available through the Enthought package manager.

The more serious problem however, is that Enthought seem to have erroneously omitted the two myole4ax.* files which are necessary to use the activex container in wx Python. You can copy these files by downloading the wxPython-src tarball from the [project page](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php), and copying the two myole4ax.* files (e.g. from wxPython-src-2.8.12.1\wxPython\wx\lib) to the [%python root%](http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/install_windows.html#installation-location)\Lib\site-packages\wx\lib folder.

Comment: I had the same problem and tried what you've said. Same error again. :(