# wx import error using Enthought Canopy python

Tags: wxpython, enthought, wxwidgets, canopy

Many of my packages was installed by Canopy and some programs that I have need to import wx.

When I tried it I got:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_type_class_adjust_private_offset
```

This error was explained too on [Canopy Support](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469930-wxPython-2-8-and-2-9) with no solution. I tried the sugested solution presented on [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019988/wx-lib-activex-fails-to-import-using-enthought-canopy-and-epd#_=_), and nothing happens. What have I to do?

Comment: Which version of wxpython do you need? version3.0 (Phoenix) is quite stable now. if 3.0 is ok, why not apt-get or pip? http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython#Installing_wxPython-Phoenix_using_pip

Comment: I tried it and no solution. My solution was to create Virtual Machine and install the packages that I need by this.